# Symbols of Python grammar with numbers less than 256

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, constants

In [this list](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/symbol.py) I found symbols of Python grammar, which contains in parse tree of Python source.

For example if I use

```
parser.st2tuple(parser.suite(open(SRC_FILENAME).read()))
```

for some source file `SRC_FILENAME`, I get a parse tree with following format:

```
                                        (307,
                                         (308,
                                          (309,
                                           (312,
                                            (313,
                                             (314,
                                              (315,
                                               (316,
                                                (317,
                                                 (318,
                                                  (319,
                                                   (320,
                                                    (1,
                                                     'Type'))))))))))))))))),
                                    (8,
                                     ')'))))))))))))))))),
                    (8, ')')))))))))))))))))),
   (4, ''))),
 (4, ''),
 (0, ''))
```

But all Python grammar constants in list has numbers **greater than 256**. Withal, there are many numbers in my tree, which **less than 256**.

So where can I find the description of symbols, which has numbers less than 256?

Comment: Why don't you use `ast`? It's much more readable.

Comment: Maybe they are opcodes ? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/opcode.h

Comment: @jonrsharpe , thanks. I tried to use `ast` as following: `ast.dump(ast.parse(open(SRC_FILENAME).read()))`. But I get not very readable output? Does the other way of using `ast` to get much readable tree exists?

Comment: @VeLKerr, what are you trying to do? ast.dump  can give you quite cluttered output especially for larger files

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, I need to get parse tree from python source. Then I need to walk around this tree and fill the special table (which contains classes, functions, variables and other elements)

Comment: @VeLKerr, do you mean you want to modify the source? You might find the second part of this answer useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078439/modify-function-in-decorator/31081432#31081432  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199328/how-can-i-find-python-methods-without-return-statements/30200033#30200033 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037326/how-to-textually-find-an-imported-name-in-a-module/30037842#30037842

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, no I don't want to modify the source. I only want to **analyze** it.

Comment: Then ast.dump is probably  good as you will get bar using nodeVisitor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81732/discussion-between-velkerr-and-padraic-cunningham).