# Add decorator for python requests get function

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests

I was looking for a way to add some sort of decorator that applies to all instances of `requests.get` being used in any function.

For example,

```
@my_custom_decorator
def hello():
    ...
    r = requests.get('https://my-api-url')
    ...
```

The `my_custom_decorator` could then add a common param (or anything else) for all instances of `requests.get`. One will only need to add the decorator whereever `requests.get` is being used.

For now, I'm thinking of somehow checking if the original function contains presence of `requests.get`, but that seems not to be ideal.

**Note:** Also,  I'm looking not to change any existing instances of `requests.get`..hence looking for a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think a decorator is the best way to solve this, maybe you should write your own `get` function instead, which calls the `requests.get` and adds whatever behaviour you want?

Comment: @FlorentMonin is it possible if you can please point me or share few links/resources which can be helpful and I can take inspiration from?

Comment: @FlorentMonin just to add:  I'm looking not to change any instances of `requests.get`..hence a decorator came to my mind.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "not change any instances of `requests.get`". I posted an answer with more details on how to create a function that would implement the behaviour change you want

Comment: @xan, *my_custom_decorator could then add a common param (or anything else)* - can you post some real-case common params which should be applied by such custom decorator?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, let's say my application has 100+ servers and want to pass a "server_id" (as param or even a header) for all requests from the application layer without touching/modifying a lot of existing code.

Comment: @xan, do you have a lot of `requests.get` calls which you want to leave unchanged or can you switch to `requests.Session` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, if there's a way with using `requests.Session` - that would help too to some extent! We have a mixture of both.

Comment: What behavior do you expect if `request.get` is called in a function `foo` called by `hello`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unittest.mock.patch` as a decorator on functions where `requests.get` needs additional parameters:

```
import requests
from unittest.mock import patch

def get(url, params=None, orig_get=requests.get, **kwargs):
    return orig_get(url, {**(params or {}), 'extra_param': 'extra_value'}, **kwargs)

my_custom_decorator = patch('requests.get', get)
```

so that:

```
@my_custom_decorator
def hello():
    r = requests.get('https://my-api-url', {'foo': 'bar'})
    print(r.status_code)

hello()
```

would send a GET request to the web server at `my-api-url` with the following URI:

```
/?foo=bar&extra_param=extra_value
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be very painful to use a decorator to solve this, since you would need to parse the code in the function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078439/modify-function-in-decorator) for instance).

Creating your own `get` function would probably be more suited for your case (though it depends on what you actually want to do)

something like:

```py
def get_with_param(url: str):
    # for instance, add a query param:
    r = requests.get(url + "?param=something")
    return r
```

and then you just have to replace every occurence of `requests.get` with `get_with_param`, for instance

Comment: actually, I wanted to avoid this way as then I will have to replace every occurence of `requests.get`. I was trying to figure out any other way of avoiding this.

Comment: @xan But now you will still need to wrap every function using `requests.get` with your decorator, so it sounds like the same amount of work.
Also, it will be much easier to understand and debug this solution, as it uses a clear function rather than changing params to an existing function "behind the scenes".

Comment: @BarakFatal not the same amount since adding a decorator is much more easy and eliminates a lot of testing compared to actual code changes. Apart from a decorator, do you see any other workaround? maybe a wrapper?

Comment: @xan so my personal opinion is that a "workaround" might be a bad idea. For the very least it will be a non-trivial solution, which means anyone else working on your code base would have to know about it. That's why I agree with this proposed answer, as it doesn't involve any workaround, even if it means more testing.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal/recommended depending on the context, but in the abscence of one, you are best placed to decide this. You could also try [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) to `monkeypatch` `requests.get`.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from requests import get as my_requests
import requests

def my_get(*args, **kwargs):
    ''' Your version of get where you do what needs to be done'''
    return my_requests(*args, **kwargs)

with patch('requests.get', my_get): # where you provide an alternate implementation for requests.get
    requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can't change "the instance" of `requests.get` because it returns

```py
:return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
```

So, I recommend the next solution (requests's `params` was used for show case):

```py
def my_custom_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        params={"search":"string"}
        return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

And, yeah, there is no way to avoid `**kwargs`:

```py
@my_custom_decorator
def hello(**kwargs):
    resp = requests.get('https://mail.ru', **kwargs)
```

Take a look PoWs (before and after):
[image]
[image]

Comment: @xan btw,  you can remove `params` entries from decorator, and use my solution this way: `hello(params={"search":"string"})` to achieve same result!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking not to change any existing instances of requests.get

Is there a specific reason for that? Temporarily overriding `requests.get` seems to be a feasible solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests

def deco(f):
  def my_fun(self):
    return "requests.get was overridden!"

  def inner():
    backup_fun = requests.get 
    requests.get = my_fun
    ret = f()
    requests.get = backup_fun
    return ret

  return inner

@deco
def decorated():
  return requests.get("http://example.org")

def undecorated():
  return requests.get("http://example.org")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("decorated:", decorated())
  print("undecorated:", undecorated())
```

Will print:

```
decorated: requests.get was overridden!
undecorated: <Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can modify and/or add other parameters like here where I modify the `url` parameter for `some_requests_dot_get_function` via `some_decorator`:

```
url = 'google.com'#'https://www.google.com/'
def some_decorator(some_function):
    def wrapper(*args, url, **kwargs):
        some_function.url = 'https://www.' + url + '/'
        return some_function(*args, url=some_function.url, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@some_decorator
def some_requests_dot_get_function(*args, url, **kwargs):
    return requests.get(*args, url=url, **kwargs).content.decode('utf-8')

some_requests_dot_get_function(url=url)
```

Not sure the exact use case you're intending, but maybe it could justify using some `dict` `annotations` for different functions to modify parameters depending on its particular `item`(s), **that way at least you only have to modify this decorator rather than every function it decorates**:

```
url = 'google.com'#'https://www.google.com/'
def some_decorator(some_function):
    def wrapper(*args, url, **kwargs):
        if some_function.__annotations__['return'].__getitem__('some_annotation') > 0:
            some_function.url = 'https://www.' + url + '/'
        else:
            some_function.url = url
        return some_function(*args, url=some_function.url, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@some_decorator
def some_requests_dot_get_function(*args, url, **kwargs) -> {'some_annotation': 2}:
    return requests.get(*args, url=url, **kwargs).content.decode('utf-8')

some_requests_dot_get_function(url=url)
```

... or we could rely on the names of the functions to set the parameters in `some_decorator`:

```
url = 'google.com'#'https://www.google.com/'
def some_decorator(some_function):
    def wrapper(*args, url, **kwargs):
        if some_function.__name__.__contains__('some_requests'):
            some_function.url = 'https://www.' + url + '/'
        elif some_function.__name__.__contains__('some_other_requests'):
            some_function.url = 'https://www.' + url + '/?client=safari'
        else:
            some_function.url = url
        return some_function(*args, url=some_function.url, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@some_decorator
def some_requests_dot_get_function(*args, url, **kwargs):
    return 'some: ' + requests.get(*args, url=url, **kwargs).content.decode('utf-8')

@some_decorator
def some_other_requests_dot_get_function(*args, url, **kwargs):
    return 'some other: ' + requests.get(*args, url=url, **kwargs).content.decode('utf-8')

some_requests_dot_get_function(url=url)
some_other_requests_dot_get_function(url=url)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will adjust the behavior for methods that make a call to `requests.get` using the decorator `my_custom_decorator`. Given that changes to the source code directly or injecting a new method using `exec` with `inspect` and `optparse` was illegal.

There is one limitation, that is that a `kwarg_ball` has to be used to mediate the decorator and the `requests.get` method, as there is no other way for injecting additional `*args, **kwargs`.

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps


def my_custom_decorator(f):
    # Filter hotkeys access if there's currently some activity going on...
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        # Have to know ahead of time if there is going to be a call made, no way around it
        source_code = inspect.getsource(f)
        if 'requests.get' in source_code:
            requests.kwarg_ball = {'DATE': 'FOO', 'VAR': 'BAR'}
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            requests.kwarg_ball = None
        else:
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return result

    return wrap


class requests:
    kwarg_ball = None

    @staticmethod
    def get(url):
        if requests.kwarg_ball is not None:
            print("Decorator modification detected!")
            for k, v in requests.kwarg_ball.items():
                print(k, ' - ', v)
        print(f'URL {url}')
```

The following produce the desire result with `hello` demonstrating the modified behavior, and `goodbye` executing normally.

```
@an_ugly_wrapper
def hello():
    requests.get('https://my-api-url')

def goodbye():
    requests.get('https://my-api-url')

hello()
goodbye()
```

Additionally, the `kwarg_ball` may be loaded into the `**kwargs` for the `requests.get` method.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you don't want to change all occurrences, what you could do, is create a new file with name **api.py** (or whatever you like) and add all the function you want like this:

```
################## api.py ########################
import requests
def get(url, params=None):
    ..... You code goes here
    return request.get(url,params)
def post(url, params=None):
    ..... You code goes here
    return request.post(url,params)
```

Now, in your code files, just replace `import requests` with `import api as requests`